# R - Regex whitespace pattern matches excessively

Tags: r, regex

I have what seems like a simple regular expression I want to match on and replace. I'm processing a bunch of free form text and respondents have a variety of ways of denoting a line break.  One such is at least 4 sequential bits of whitespace. Another is a heavy dot.  However, in R (`perl=FALSE`) I get some very strange behavior.  The regex `\\s{4,}|•` replaces the whole string with one `<br>`, if I change the repetition to be just 4 (`\\s{4}|•`) then it returns 19 `<br>`. If I remove the `|•` then it works fine. If I explicitly call out 4 whitespace characters or the heavy dot, `\\s\\s\\s\\s+|•`, it works fine.

What is it about repeating `\\s` or checking for a heavy dot `•` that causes such erratic behavior?

```
x = "Call Narrative <br>11/15/2017          19:53:00            J574511 <br> <br>"
replacement = "<br>"

orig_pattern = "\\s{4,}|•"
alt1 = "\\s\\s\\s\\s+|•"
alt2 = "\\s{4,}"
alt3 = "\\s{4,}|<p>"
alt4 = "\\s{4}|•"

gsub(orig_pattern,replacement,x)
#> [1] "<br>"

gsub(alt1,replacement,x)
#> [1] "Call Narrative <br>11/15/2017<br>19:53:00<br>J574511 <br> <br>"

gsub(alt2,replacement,x)
#> [1] "Call Narrative <br>11/15/2017<br>19:53:00<br>J574511 <br> <br>"

gsub(alt3,replacement,x)
#> [1] "Call Narrative <br>11/15/2017<br>19:53:00<br>J574511 <br> <br>"

gsub(alt4,replacement,x)
#> [1] "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>"
```

*UPDATE*
It seems to be associated with the OS. The problem originated on Amazon Linux 2 but works fine on Windows.

Comment: `> gsub(orig_pattern,replacement,x)` => `[1] "Call Narrative <br>11/15/2017<br>19:53:00<br>J574511 <br> <br>"`. It seems there is some issue with your testing environment. What OS is that?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I don't get that behavior on Amazon Linux 2, R 3.4.3

Comment: Use PCRE, `perl=TRUE`, then. It seems the default TRE is buggy there.